# Java parsing unicode math. formula from JSON

Tags: java, unicode

We're trying to parse JSON element that contains some unicode characters and display the result in a HTML page.

Raw JSON element:

```
"[G\u2061(x|fm\u2062\u2062i\u2062\u2062n,fm\u2062\u2062ax,σ)={exp\u2061(-(fm\u2062\u2062i\u2062\u2062n-x)2/σ2)\u2062\u2062x<fm\u2062\u2062i\u2062\u2062n1,fm\u2062\u2062i\u2062\u2062n<x<fm\u2062\u2062axexp\u2061(-(fm\u2062\u2062ax-x)2/σ2)\u2062\u2062x>fm\u2062\u2062ax(3)]"
```

Expected result after parsing:

```
G ⁡ ( x | f m ⁢ ⁢ i ⁢ ⁢ n , f m ⁢ ⁢ ax , σ ) = { exp ⁡ ( - ( f m ⁢ ⁢ i ⁢ ⁢ n - x ) 2 / σ 2 ) ⁢ ⁢ x < f m ⁢ ⁢ i ⁢ ⁢ n 1 , f m ⁢ ⁢ i ⁢ ⁢ n < x < f m ⁢ ⁢ ax exp ⁡ ( - ( f m ⁢ ⁢ ax - x ) 2 / σ 2 ) ⁢ ⁢ x > f m ⁢ ⁢ ax ( 3 )
```

Actual result taken from HTML page:

```
Gâ�¡(x|fmâ�¢â�¢iâ�¢â�¢n,fmâ�¢â�¢ax,Ïƒ)={expâ�¡(-(fmâ�¢â�¢iâ�¢â�¢n-x)2/Ïƒ2)â�¢â�¢xfmâ�¢â�¢ax(3)
```

Actual result taken from Chrome's dev. console:

```
Gâ�¡(x|fmâ�¢â�¢iâ�¢â�¢n,fmâ�¢â�¢ax,Ïƒ)\u003d{expâ�¡(-(fmâ�¢â�¢iâ�¢â�¢n-x)2/Ïƒ2)â�¢â�¢x\u003cfmâ�¢â�¢iâ�¢â�¢n1,fmâ�¢â�¢iâ�¢â�¢n\u003cx\u003cfmâ�¢â�¢axexpâ�¡(-(fmâ�¢â�¢ax-x)2/Ïƒ2)â�¢â�¢x\u003efmâ�¢â�¢ax(3)
```

The JSON is fetched from an external system over an HTTP call. We first used Retrofit 2.0 and then switched to Apache HttpComponents 4.5.6 thinking this might solve something. It didn't.

The code snippet used for getting the JSON:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", authToken);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
HttpEntity entity;
try {
    entity = new ByteArrayEntity(requestString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), writer, "UTF-8");
    LOGGER.debug(writer.toString());
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    LOGGER.error("HTTP callout failed! ", ioException);
}
```

We're using JDK 1.8.0.

Comment: It looks to me as if the problem happens when you display the string on the HTML page. Are you sure the HTML page uses UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: The page's meta charset is set to UTF-8. It doesn't seems to be a view problem since we're getting the same wrong result in the IDE console.

Answer (score 0):

What you get is the result of a twice utf8 encoding. You have done this:

original utf8 byte string -> unicode (char) string **decoded as ISO-8859-1 aka latin1** -> re-encoded as utf8.

The correct way would be understand the real cause(*). But a quick and dirty fix is to simply encode with the Latin1 charset to get a no-op (byte string -> Latin1 decoded -> Latin1 encoded):

```
IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), writer, "Latin1");
```

---

(*) Just a wild guess, but JSON can explicitely encode unicode in a plain ASCII string. Here the initial bytes of your string would be (along with their hexa ascii code):

[ (0x5d) " (0x22) G (0x47) u (0x5c) \ (0x75) 2 (0x32) 0 (0x30) ...

In that case, the decoding should be done at the JSON level and should directly give a char string

Comment: Regarding the "dirty fix": is this really something we should advise people to do? Most of the time a clean fix (i.e. fix at the place where the `String` is first constructed) is not more difficult and has the advantage to really work with all characters.